# Executing code at some point of time swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, time, background

I'm making app where user set some point of time, for example 10 am, and at 10 am I want to execute some code, for example I want to print "Wake up!". Which type of background working or something different should I use? I want to add also options to set different days when code have to execute.

PS. I want to it will execute even while app will be terminated, something like alarm clock

Comment: Schedule a notification

Comment: But can I only execute code ? I won't print "Wake up!" and I'm not writing alarm clock, that was only example. I want to execute code(short code) in my app.

Comment: Just check if that date has passed and execute it when the user opens your app again

Answer (score -2):

You can use this pod to accomplish this.

https://github.com/radex/SwiftyTimer

```
Timer.after(6.hours) {
   println("Time to wake up!!")
}
```

Comment: Yes, timer is one of the few services that can run in the background, along with location, and downloads

Comment: No, it isn't.  Timers do not run in the background, and certainly not if the app is terminated.